# parsing xml file from sd card to console

Tags: android

I am still very green in Android but I have managed to create an xml file, pushed it into the sd card of my emulator. Can somebody help me on how I can read the xml file from my emulator and print its values on the console or on the ListView.

I will very much appreciate

Answer (score 0):

> how I can read the xml file from my
>   emulator

You have to use an XML parser. You have [DOM,SAX and the pull-parser](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) available on android. 
Go through that article and you will be able to read data from your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this article ... http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.com/2010/09/generic-xml-parsing-in-android.html .. probably this can give you an insight for DOM xml parsing.